# How to git clone with external linked repositories in branch?

Tags: git, clone

I trying git clone this case.

For example in git branch:

- external repo 1 @ 797131b
- external repo 2 @ 04a1ffe
- external repo 3 @ b8132df

It is external linked repositories in branch.

I want git clone repository with external linked repositories.

But, I can only check empty directory after git clone.

How to clone git repository with external linked repositories in once try?

Comment: you mean cherry-pick certain commits from a given branch ?

Comment: read this : https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To automatically initialize and update each submodule in the repository, pass `--recursive` to the `git clone`:

```
git clone --recursive <repoAddress>
```

More about submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thank you very so much. Good Luck.